# Which theorems for finite limits remain true for infinite limits?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits

Which theorems for finite limits remain true for infinite limits? The algebra of limits follows. What are the other properties and theorems that follow? How to check? On which theorems should I check?

Comment: A lot of things. You just have to take care in defining what a limit at infinity means. A common real analysis definition is that, given $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}: |a_n-a|<\epsilon\, $ for all $n \ge N$. There are nicer ways to rigorously define this, such as One-Point Compactification for both real and complex numbers, but since you clearly have little introduction to this topic that's probably a bit beyond what you should worry about for now.

Comment: Unclear. What means "infinite limits"? Limits with *variable* $\to\infty$ or limits with *function* $\to\infty$?

Comment: Obviously. With functions

Comment: @Mathhacker is this a good example.

Answer (score 0):

If, near $x=a $,

$$f (x)<g (x)  $$
then
$$\lim_af (x)\le \lim_ag (x) $$

Comment: Really? What if $f \to 0$ and $g \to \infty$?

Comment: @HansLundmark Thnx. I edited new.